# Spin magnetic moment and external magnetic field, stable state

Tags: solid-state-physics, magnetic-moment

I am having a hard time understanding when the electronic state, represents a more stable state, when we consider an electron with spin exposed to an external magnetic field.

The spin magnetic moment is:

$$\vec \mu_s=-g_e \frac{e}{2m_e}\vec S$$

This implies that the spin magnetic moment it's anti-parallel to the spin.

For the z-component of the spin magn. moment we have:

$$\mu_{s_z}=-g_s\mu_bm_s$$

where $m_b$ is the bohr magneton and $m_s$ is the spin quantum number (+/-\frac{1}{2})

Now, I am considering a magnetic field pointing in th z-direction, than for the energy of an object (electron in this case) that has magnetic moment, it's energy in the magnetic field is:

$$E=-\vec \mu \vec B$$

Since we said that $\vec B= B\vec e_z$ than:

$$E=-\vec \mu \vec B=-\mu_{Sz}B$$

$$E=-(-g_s\mu_bm_s)B=g_s\mu_bm_sB$$

Case one: $m_s=\frac 1 2$

In this case the z spin component is aligned with the magnetic field, in other words the corresponding spin magnetic moment is anti parallel to the magnetic field. The energy for *spin aligning to the magnetic field* is:

$$E=+\mu_bB$$

Case two: $m_s=-\frac{1}{2}$

In this case the z spin component is anti-parallel with the magnetic field, in other words the corresponding spin magnetic moment is  parallel to the magnetic field. The energy for *spin anti-parallel to the magnetic field* is:

$$E=-\mu_bB$$

From the above calculations it is evident that when the spin has the same direction as the magnetic field the energy is larger compared to when the spin has the opposite direction. And we know that the less energy the state has, the more stable that state is. Meaning, in this case, when the spin points in the opposite direction of the magnetic field, the electron occupies a state that is more stable. BUT, in many lectures, books etc, I always read that when the spin points in the same direction as the magnetic field, that is the most stable state, and intuitively it makes more sense, because an electron with a spin in the opposite direction to the magnetic field, all it needs is a bit of perturbation, to eventually, because of torque, to align itself with the magnetic field (the z-component of spin)
. So what is it that I am doing wrong in my calculations or my understanding?